# Pandas:Find the repeating patterns in a column and group them as cycles

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a column with values 'loading', 'unloading','nan'. I want to look for the pattern of 'loading' and 'unloading' in that order and mark those corresponding rows as cycle1, cycle2 so on.

[image]

The pic shows one such sequence where 'loading' and 'unloading' and I want a new column to have the values of '1' for all those rows and the next sequence of 'loading' and 'unloading' as '2' so on.

I've got no logic to show you but would appreciate if you can help me. The below pic shows what I expect

[image]

Comment: I think I did not understand the requirement " I want a new column to have the values of '1' for all those rows and the next sequence of 'loading' and".... can you add a table with the expected output to clarify the description, Do you mean you want to derive a column with 1 for loading and 2 for unloading events? or the LEAD event?

Comment: @SaulCruz, Please find the sample output I posted I expect. Each cycle has loading sequence and unloading sequence in that order.1, 2,3 in the cycle's column represent the order of the cycles in which they occur.

Comment: Post your samples as formatted text instead of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a loop based way to do it. I'd be excited if someone else has a way that better makes use of pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Event': ['Start','Going','Stop','Start','Stop','Start','Start','Going','Going','Going','Stop','Stop','Start','Stop']}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

cycle = 0            
new_cycle = True
cycles = []
for x in df.Event:
    if new_cycle and x == 'Start':
        new_cycle = False
        cycle += 1
    elif x == 'Stop':
        new_cycle = True
    cycles.append(cycle)

df['cycles'] = cycles
print(df)
```

Output

```
    Event  cycles
0   Start       1
1   Going       1
2    Stop       1
3   Start       2
4    Stop       2
5   Start       3
6   Start       3
7   Going       3
8   Going       3
9   Going       3
10   Stop       3
11   Stop       3
12  Start       4
13   Stop       4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it shifting the dataframe with something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'event': ['loading','loading','loading','unloading','unloading',
'loading','unloading','unloading','loading','loading','loading',
'loading','loading','loading']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_shifted= df[["event"]].shift()

# serie of booleans
condition_results = ((df["event"] == "loading") & (df_shifted["event"]=="unloading")) 

df["cycle"] = (condition_results).cumsum() #cumsum adds one on each true
```

[image: Results]